# Scroll UICollectionView to bottom, when Keyboard is shown

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, keyboard, swift5, collectionview

I have a chat in my app. And I want the bottom of the collectionView of the chat to be attached to the keyboard. Meaning when the keyboard appears, the last message moves up with the keyboard.

I am currently calling this function in my `viewDidLoad()`

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
}
```

But that does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any error messages you got would be helpful

Comment: No error messages @Tadreik.

Comment: @alionako, the notification works. However it gets called every time I go into the Chat and whenever I press any key on the keyboard or tap somewhere on the screen ...
The text field and sendbutton are in a containerView and I call the containerView in `override var inputAccessoryView: UIView?`. Is that the mistake?

Comment: I think you should put the scrollTo method inside the textfield(didBeginEditing:) delegate, since as soon as the textfield starts editing, it will show the keyboard.

Comment: Also note: Add a method to your collectionView's scrolling started delegate to do textField.resignFirstResponder(), to make sure textfield(didBeginEditing:) is called every time it is tapped.

Comment: Okay, I just found out, that it jumps to the bottom, when I type something in. But I cannot use my MacBook keyboard, I have to use the keyboard within the simulator, that's why I didn't work the whole time. But still, I want the collectionView to be right at the bottom, as soon as I go into the chat and as soon as the keyboard opens...

Answer (score 3):

Solved it! Here is how I did it:

In my sendButton I added a target, to make sure, the collectionView stays at the bottom, when ever a message is sent:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(keyboardWillShoww), for: .touchUpInside)
```

This is the @objc func keyboardWillShoww (yes, I am aware of the spelling mistake):

```
  @objc func keyboardWillShoww() {
    
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)

}
```

This made sure, the collectionView will stay at the bottom, when I use the button.

Next step was to make sure, the collectionView stays at the bottom, when the keyboard appears, I type something in and when the collectionView itself appears. This is how I did it:

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let section = 0
    let lastItemIndex = self.collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) - 1
    let indexPath:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath.init(item: lastItemIndex, section: section)
    self.collectionView!.scrollToItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
    
}
```

And since my textField and sendButton are within a containerView, I had to make sure, that the last collectionView cell stays attached to the top of the containerView. This is how I did it:

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    
    
    get {
        
        let section = 0
    let lastItemIndex = self.collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) - 1
    let indexPath:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath.init(item: lastItemIndex, section: section)
    self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
        
        return containerView
    }
    
}
```

So you see, I am calling the same function (scrollToItem) at multiple places, I am sure, there is a more elegant way to get the result, I longed for, but this works perfectly fine and does exactly, what I want it to do.

One last thing: I recommend you **not** to use

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    <#code#>
}
```

and call the scrollToItem function there, as that will disable the scroll function, because it does that the collectionView bottom always stays on top of the containerView/keyboard.

I hope my brief instruction will help whoever was trying to do, what I was trying to do.
Best!

PS: I recommend you to set `animated` to false, because the animation takes a lot of time and it does not look good. But look for yourself.